# How to stop page refreshing when textbox autopostback is true in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback

I have a textbox under gridview which has autopostback property true,so the page always gets refreshed.But i dont want the page to be refreshed.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDates" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="440px"
                                                    GridLines="None">
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ds" HeaderStyle-Width="110px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#993300"
                                                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Onkeyup="" Text='<%#Eval("Ds") %>'
                                                                    OnTextChanged="txt_TextChanged" ToolTip='<%#Eval("Ds") %>' CssClass="txtboxDiff"
                                                                    Width="110px" onmouseover="setToolTip(this)" onblur="Check(this)" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderdocsdate" runat="server" PopupButtonID=""
                                                                    Format="dd-MM-yyyy" TargetControlID="txt">
                                                                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        /Columns>
                                                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Why not just `AutoPostBack="False"`?

Comment: It is the requirement i cant not make it.@Anderi

Comment: Can you post your requirement to why you have done so ? Maybe someone can give you an alternate idea to tackle this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Gridview inside an ajax update panel...

```
     <asp:GridView ID="grdDates" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="440px"
              GridLines="None">
                 <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ds" HeaderStyle-Width="110px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#993300"
                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
               <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Onkeyup="" Text='<%#Eval("Ds") %>'
                OnTextChanged="txt_TextChanged" ToolTip='<%#Eval("Ds") %>' CssClass="txtboxDiff"
                Width="110px" onmouseover="setToolTip(this)" onblur="Check(this)" AutoPostBack="True">   </asp:TextBox>

               <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderdocsdate" runat="server" PopupButtonID=""
               Format="dd-MM-yyyy" TargetControlID="txt">
               </asp:CalendarExtender>
               </ContentTemplate>


              <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txt" />
              </Triggers>    


               </asp:UpdatePanel>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </Columns>
               </asp:GridView>
```

Place a scriptmanager..

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Answer updated..Place the update panel inside ItemTemplate covering the textbox,Regards..

Comment: Please try setting trigger for the update panel as shown..Answer updated,Regards..